# Text underflow with high rep and badges after editing a post

Tags: bug, design

A minor issue to be sure, and perhaps an edge case, but...

When a user has a fairly high reputation and a good number of badges, and edits a post by someone else, the user card can get truncated. Like so:

[image: screen shot]

Note that the "106" next to the bronze badge icon is overwritten by the user card next to it.

This is on Google Chrome 29. I also see it on Firefox 23 but not IE 10. (All on Windows 7.)

Comment: Doesn't occur in Firefox 26, but still here in Chrome 32.